# Custom Content Type not showing up in List

Tags: list, sharepoint-server, content-type, custom-control

I need to develop a way for cross-site lookup in Sharepoint 2013. As this is not possible OOTB, I built a custom content type that has a custom control template which in turn displays a custom form with custom controls that make cross site lookup possible.

Everything down from the custom control template works as I also use this for another cross site lookup solution. The custom content type is also OK as it shows up in site content types with all it's proper custom columns displaying. So the fault has to lie within my custom list's schema.xml. However, I cannot seem to find the error. I have posted below relevant definitions:

Custom list definition:

[image]

Custom content type definiton:

[image]

Custom list's `Elements.xml`:

[image]

I need to cover the values because they contain sensitive info and this is for my company. Anyway, as you can see, I use SP standard columns `Title`, `LinkTitle` and `LinkTitleNoMenu` in my definitions. All the columns you see here are plain text columns, and no matter what I put in my control template (even only a  element), it does not show up either when I click new item. I just get a blank background.

EDIT: Maybe I should mention that I get an ULS log entry when I try to view the custom form. The specific message is that `FormTemplate` (the list's custom form template) cannot be found. The error message contains nothing else and has the severity medium. And please ignore the typo in the custom list's `Elements.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys after searching through every bit of code and markup in my files, I found the problem. Apparently, Sharepoint finds it enough to just say "I can't find the form template" when it actually means "The form template cannot load due to declared control not being rendered correctly".

The problem was, after all, in the custom form. I still had it referenced in the form template, as soon as I removed that, the form template loaded correctly. After a while I noticed that some server side events where called differently in markup and code behind. After correcting this error, everything rendered without problem.

Microsoft and their error messages, gotta love em. :)